# How to Validate User Session with Cookies in Next.js on Page Reload using the App router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js application where I need to validate the user's session by checking a cookie against my API whenever the user reloads the website or navigates to it. I'm trying to implement this logic in my root layout component. The idea is to use the useUser hook from my UserContext to set the user's data if the cookie is valid.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { UserProvider, useUser } from '@/context/UserContext';


async function getData() {
  const token = Cookies.get('auth_token');
  const { setUser } = useUser();

  if (token) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://your-api-endpoint/user', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      });
      console.log('Session validated successfully:', response);
      setUser(response.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Session validation failed:', error);
      Cookies.remove('auth_token');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No token found');
  }
}

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  await getData();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <UserProvider>
          {children}
        </UserProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

However, I'm getting an error saying:

```
Error: Attempted to call useUser() from the server but useUser is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `useUser` in a server component because it needs the context and contexts are a client-side feature in next-js.

Normaly the RootLayout has to be a server-component in next-js so i'm not sure if you can use the UserProvider in there? Perhabs you have to move the UserProvider into a sub-component.

If you want to access the user-data from a client-component, you would have to move the `getDate` logic into a route and then access it via fetch from the client-component.

There are tutorials (https://www.makeuseof.com/token-authentication-nextjs-using-jwt/) and libraries like `next-auth` which can help you implement a JWT-Authentication in next-js.

JWT is a standard one uses normally when doing such a token-authentication.

Comment: ran into some complexity while using `next-auth` in my custom API. i still will need to revalidate my token from the server upon refresh which is why i was running it at the root of the file

Comment: basically all the tutorials have been the same so far, and next-auth does not do a validation of my keys with my custom API that is built as a microservice.

Comment: If you want to have the user in your client-side context, you have to pass it to the client. For example with a route.

Comment: You cannot set the context from the server component.

Comment: actually i was able to set the context on the server side and it is possible to do that, but it only happens on one condition, and that is if that is where the context wrapper is. and in the code where i asked the question, it was possible by passing it as a props.

Comment: I actually did not know that you can use context on the server side. But nice to know, that this is possible! :). 
Is your original problem solved with this or do you have any more Problems?